# Percentage of Tax Year Remaining

Tags: php, excel, date, datetime

I managed to do this on excel by using the following (note that I use the dd/mm/yyyy date format:)

User inputs Date assigned to cell A1`01/01/2007`

Calculation to find out current tax year `=IF(MONTH(A1)<>4,YEAR(A1)-1,IF(DAY(A1)>=6,YEAR(A1),YEAR(A1)-1))` Result is the current tax year is year `2006`

That Date's Tax year begins = `=DATE(A1,4,6)` result of `06/04/2006`

Day before the Tax year ends = `=DATE(R54+1,4,5)` result of `05/04/2007`

Max number of days `=ABS((R55-R56))+1` result = `365` (used to detect leap years)

Number of days passed in the tax year `=ABS(R53-R55-R57)` result = `95`

Works out percentage of tax year left `=(R58/R57)*100` result is `26.02739726`

Now i need to do the same in PHP, and honestly have no idea where to start.

Comment: How about a formula that **doesn't** involve excel syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use PHP's [`DateTime` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and the [`DateTime::diff` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
<?php
$tz = new DateTimeZone("UTC"); // Set to one of the supported time zones: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
$tax_year_begin_dt = new DateTime("2006-04-06", $tz);
$tax_year_end_dt = new DateTime("2007-04-06", $tz);
$num_days_in_tax_year = $tax_year_begin_dt->diff($tax_year_end_dt)->days;
echo "\$num_days_in_tax_year = $num_days_in_tax_year<br>\n";
$dt = new DateTime("2007-01-01", $tz);
$num_days_remaining = $dt->diff($tax_year_end_dt)->days;
echo "\$num_days_remaining = $num_days_remaining<br>\n";
$percent_remaining = 100.0*$num_days_remaining/$num_days_in_tax_year;
echo "$percent_remaining%<br>\n";
```

The output of this code is:

```
$num_days_in_tax_year = 365
$num_days_remaining = 95
26.027397260274%
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/WNxRHS